# SBJson Parser without memory leaks, iphone

Tags: iphone, sbjson

i used SBJson parser in my project but getting some memory leaks, all those are SBJson parser.

can any one tell me what is version of SBJson parser do i need to use to avoid the leaks.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using now?
The most recently release version of SBJson is 3.0.3, if you still have problem with it you can try the newest test version 3.1 alpha1

https://github.com/stig/json-framework/tree/v3.0.3